# Constructing a string to be used as command in bash

Tags: bash, pipe

I want to construct a string which calls an executable and pipes its output through a chain of commands like 'grep', 'gawk', 'sed' etc., e.g.

```
a=`./process t1.txt 7 | grep -v 'head' | grep -e '^42' -e '^13' | xargs | gawk '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/ /;/g'`
```

However, the arguments to 'process' as well as the entire chain of commands are only determined at run time.
So i would need to be able to do something like

```
f1="'^42'"
f3="'^13'"
p=2
filterchain="grep -v 'head' | grep -e $f1 -e $f2 | xargs | gawk '{ print \$$p }' | sed 's/ /;/g'"
cmd="./process ${testfile} ${col} |  ${filterchain}"
a=`${cmd}`
```

But this approach does not work, even though the string $cmd looks exactly like the one above.

How does such a string have to look in order to be executable from a bash script (e.g. with the backquotes)?

Comment: Maybe you are using $f2 instead of $f3 ? (incorrect variable name)

Comment: Read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: You need another approach for your script. You can make many functions for every case.

Answer (score 2):

Use functions.

```
filterchain () {
  grep -v head | 
   grep -e "$1" -e "$2" |
   xargs |
   gawk -v p="$3" '{print $p}' |
   sed 's/ /;/g'
}
cmd () {
  ./process "$1" "$2" | filterchain "$3" "$4" "$5"
}
a=$(cmd "$testfile" "$col" "^42" "^13" 2)
```

Comment: This works well if the structure of the filter chain remains the same. Could functions be written during runtime and then executed in bash?

Comment: Not easily; the shell is intended to *run* commands, not manipulate them. Functions are not first-class objects.

Comment: Your solution is right. I have deleted my post and upvoted your. Reading better the code maybe this is the only way to do clean things.